# Subquery not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query to query insurance policies from my database. Everything is working except for the subquery portions of my query. I've been looking at it for awhile now and can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

```
$approvedPolicies = InsurancePolicy::join( 'proofs', 'insurance_policies.id', '=', 'proofs.insurance_policy_id' )
        ->where( 'insurance_policies.resident_id', $resident->id )
        ->where( 'insurance_policies.policy_title', '!=', 'Master Policy' )
        ->where( function ( $query ){
            $query->orWhere( 'cancel_date', 'IS', 'NULL' )
                ->orWhere( 'cancel_date', '0001-01-01 00:00:00' )
                ->orWhere( 'cancel_date', '>', 'NOW()' );
        } ) // this subquery causes issue
        ->where( function ( $query ){
            $query->orWhere( 'expiration_date', 'IS', 'NULL' )
                ->orWhere( 'expiration_date', '0001-01-01 00:00:00' )
                ->orWhere( 'expiration_date', '>', 'NOW()' );
        } ) // this sub query causes issue
        ->whereNull( 'insurance_policies.deleted_at' )
        ->where( 'proofs.status', 'Approved' )
        ->whereNull( 'proofs.deleted_at' )
        ->get();
```

Based on the data in my database these queries should not be returning null, but when these subqueries are being executed my $approvedPolicies array is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after your query to get the last executed query and check if that the correct query you wanted to execute.

Comment: try `->orWhereNull('cancel_date')` instead of `->orWhere( 'cancel_date', 'IS', 'NULL' )` and replace `'NOW()'` with `Carbon::now()`